# Class 'Future<dynamic>' has no instance method '[]'

Tags: android, dart, async-await

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olo8i.png)Future dynamic not working please help trying to make a weather app

```
  class WeatherModel {
  Future<dynamic> getLocationWeather() async{
    Location location = Location();
    await location.getCurrentLocation();

    Networkhelper networkhelper = Networkhelper(
        '$openWeatherMapURL
    lat=${location.latitude}&lon=${location.longitude}&appid=$apiKey&units=metric');

    var weatherData = await networkhelper.getData();
    return weatherData;
   }}
```

Comment: There is nothing in the posted code that could throw this error. Did you maybe mean to `return weatherData;` and you are trying to access the return value somewhere in code you have not posted here?

Comment: I have applied return weatherData ; still getting the error

Comment: What line does the error appear in exactly?

Comment: I have added a photo

Comment: That photo is useless without your source code. Can you please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

your code should look like this:

Confirm your URL matches mine. Seems like you're missing `?`.

```dart
  Future<dynamic> getLocationWeather() async {
    Location location = Location();
    await location.getCurrentLocation();

    NetworkHelper networkHelper = NetworkHelper(
        url:                                // if you used a positional argument.     
            '$openWeatherMapURL?lat=${location.latitude}&lon=${location.longitude}&appid=$apiKey&units=metric');

    var weatherData = await networkHelper.getData();
    return weatherData;
  }
```

Comment: this is giving error

Comment: what error, can you send a screenshot.? Have you already fixed it?